# Nuance of Javascript Regex Word Boundaries?

Tags: javascript, regex

Test string:

AS/ANZ 1234

Regex:

```
\bAS\b
```

matches:

AS

If \b is shorthand for:

```
(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

Why Regex:

```
(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)AS(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

Finds no matches?

**Update** (Based on questions in comments)
I'm trying to solve my own problems before asking questions. Testing regex at https://regex101.com/

I entered:

```
\bAS\b
```

The Explanation (on the right-hand side), indicates it's shorthand for:

```
(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)AS(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

Granted, I may very well be misinterpreting the Explanation.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your shorthand for word boundaries.  I think that `\b` will also match to the starting and closing anchors.

Comment: I think the `\w` in your shorthand should be a non-capturing group!

Comment: The `\b` thing involves lookahead.

Comment: `\b` is shorthand for `[^\w]` (or `\W` which is the same thing) in JavaScript - it matches any non-word character. \ is a non-word character. Who said that `\b` is shorthand for (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W) ?

Comment: It's more like `(?:(?:^|\W)(?=\w)|\w(?=\W|$))`

Comment: @Adam No, actually that's not correct.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Whether or not a group is capturing does not affect whether it "eats" what it matches.

Comment: @Pointy: Not even that: `\b` involves lookahead *and lookbehind*, which is not otherwise possible in JavaScript.

Comment: @torazaburo - you are correct. What I meant to imply was that whatever matches `\W` will be matched by `\b`, not necessarily that they are interchangeable in any given regexp.

Comment: Updated my question in response to comments here

Comment: @Jordan - the explanation is simply wrong, as torazaburo points out in the answer below.

Comment: @Adam Thank you. I did **not** mean to imply that torazaburo is wrong. I was simply giving context and answering the implied question: "Why do you think that \b and the shorthand are equivalent?" Cheers

Comment: @Jordan - you can't believe everything you read on the internet, not even from `regex101.com` apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nuance in the definition of word boundary. It does exactly what the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) says it does. It is **zero-width**. As such, it cannot be emulated or mimicked with any regexp construct that is not zero-width, as in your example. In your example:

```
(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)AS(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
```

matched against "AS/ANZ 1234", the initial `^\w` will "eat" the "A", leaving it unavailable to be matched against "AS". The following `\w\W` will "eat" the "S", also leaving it unavailable to be matched against "S".

Comment: Thank you. That'll teach me to try to solve my own problems through testing. Just come to SO first :-D